# ReactiveCocoa's equivalent to Observable.Create

Tags: .net, objective-c, system.reactive, anonymous-class, reactive-cocoa

I'd like to make a custom RACSignal, but I'd prefer to not have to make a whole class. I just want to specify a block to call when observers subscribe.

In .Net's Rx I would do this:

```
return Observable.Create(observer => {
    ...
    // send items to observer
    ...
    return subscriptionDisposer;
});
```

Does ReactiveCocoa have equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answer: the `RACSignal` class has a `createSignal` method that acts like `Observable.Create`.

(I would have found it right away with autocomplete, but XCode's autocomplete HALF fails in lots of cases where you have half-written code above what you're editing. You get some results but not others. Bleh.)